# Installing Magento on CentOS nightmare (AVC denial)

Tags: magento

I'm trying to install Magento unto my CentOS that I'm running off Hyper-V and it's driving me crazy. I set everything up as per tutorial, but every time I reach the locale page of the setup it says "AVC denial... attempting to write to /var. I'm pretty new with linux but I tried almost everything, I did what the error told me and set the label of the /var directory and all the directories below it to httpd_sys_content_t and made sure it has write permission. After that didn't work I gave up and decided to reposition the server to a custom folder in /usr directory, I changed all the apache config files so it doesn't mention /var directory at all, but the apache process is still attempting to write to it for some reason. Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: it turns out there are also other processes that attempt to write to /var as soon as I hit that page and they're all getting blocked. Pickup and abrt-watch-log to be specific. I must be doing something wrong, if /var is such a protected directory why is it the default for apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep "denied" /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

What's there?

---

And for your information, Magento want to access file on magento folder var, **log** or **report** or **cache**

Go to your Magento folder and you can change it with

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var
```

it will give access to write and change file inside there.

Comment: I did chmod -R inside the magento directory and it didn't do anything

Comment: inside the audit.log there are all the things that are getting blocked I listed them before but abrt-watch-log and pickup are getting blocked trying to access var